# jQuery - Clone DIV with onchange event

Tags: jquery, clone, onchange, selectedindex

I have a web form, in which I am currently cloning classes with a button onclick, which is working OK. However there is a onchange (setspecificDetails;setDetails1) within the select tag which gets cloned, that screws with the cloned select options - any changes to cloned select items will update options already selected in previous sections prior to cloning as it refers back to the above onchanges.

Any ideas how can I handle this better? I was wondering if and how I can change the onchange name each time it gets cloned, and create a new onchange for each eventuality? Or maybe there is a much better, more intelligent way to do this!?

HTML:

```
<div id="entry1" class="clonedInput">
   <fieldset id="yourIssue1">
      <legend class="heading-reference">Entry #1</legend>
      <p>Please choose what your issue(s) is below. (Please note if you have multiple balances out you will need to submit each one separately)</p>
      <p>
         <label class="label_ttl">Your Request:</label>
         <select type="text" class="required select_ttl" name="request_details" id="requestdetails1" onchange="setspecificDetails(this);setDetails1(this);">
            <option value="">Select...</option>
            <option value="Trust Balance out">Trust Balance out</option>
            <option value="Bank Balance out">Bank Balance out</option>
         </select>
      </p>
   </fieldset>
   <p><label class="label_fn">Date this balance went out according to the NBS auto-validation history search in Sherlock?</label><input type="text" class="required date-picker tinyInput input_fn" id="datetrustbalanceout1" name="date_trust_balance_out"/></p>
   <p><label class="label_ln">Date this balance went out according to the NBS auto-validation history search in Sherlock?</label><input type="text" class="required date-picker tinyInput input_ln" id="datebankbalanceout1" name="date_bank_balance_out"/></p>
   <br />
   <br />
</div>
<div id="addDelButtons">
   <p><input type='button' value='add section' id='btnAdd' style='width: 200px; height: 40px' /></p>
   <p><input type='button' value='remove section above' id='btnDel' style='width: 200px; height: 40px' /></p>
</div>
<p class="submit"><input class="button" name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
```

onchange selectedIndexs:

```
     function setspecificDetails (detail) {
      if (detail.selectedIndex == 0) {
        $("#datetrustbalanceout1").hide();
        $("#datetrustbalanceout1").removeClass("required");
        $(".label_fn").hide();
        $("#datebankbalanceout1").hide();
        $("#datebankbalanceout1").removeClass("required");
        $(".label_ln").hide();
      } else if (detail.selectedIndex == 1) {
        $("#datetrustbalanceout1").show();
        $("#datetrustbalanceout1").addClass("required");
        $(".label_fn").show();
        $("#datebankbalanceout1").hide();
        $("#datebankbalanceout1").removeClass("required");
        $(".label_ln").hide();
      } else if (detail.selectedIndex == 2) {
        $("#datetrustbalanceout1").hide();
        $("#datetrustbalanceout1").removeClass("required");
        $(".label_fn").hide();
        $("#datebankbalanceout1").show();
        $("#datebankbalanceout1").addClass("required");
        $(".label_ln").show();

      }
  }
     function setDetails1 (detail) {
        if (detail.selectedIndex == 0) {
        $("#ID2_datetrustbalanceout").hide();
        $("#ID2_datetrustbalanceout").removeClass("required");
        $(".label_fn").hide();
        $("#ID2_datebankbalanceout").hide();
        $("#ID2_datebankbalanceout").removeClass("required");
        $(".label_ln").hide();
      } else if (detail.selectedIndex == 1) {
        $("#ID2_datetrustbalanceout").show();
        $("#ID2_datetrustbalanceout").addClass("required");
        $(".label_fn").show();
        $("#ID2_datebankbalanceout").hide();
        $("#ID2_datebankbalanceout").removeClass("required");
        $(".label_ln").hide();
      } else if (detail.selectedIndex == 2) {
        $("#ID2_datetrustbalanceout").hide();
        $("#ID2_datetrustbalanceout").removeClass("required");
        $(".label_fn").hide();
        $("#ID2_datebankbalanceout").show();
        $("#ID2_datebankbalanceout").addClass("required");
        $(".label_ln").show();
      }
  }
```

clone jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var num = $('.clonedInput').length, // Checks to see how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
            newNum = new Number(num + 1), // The numeric ID of the new input field being added, increasing by 1 each time
            newElem = $('#entry' + num).clone(true).attr('id', 'entry' + newNum).fadeIn('slow'); // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value

        // H2 - section
        newElem.find('.heading-reference').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_reference').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_reference').html('Entry #' + newNum);

        // Title - select
        newElem.find('.label_ttl').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_requestDetails');
        newElem.find('.select_ttl').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_requestDetails').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_requestDetails').val('');

        // First name - text
        newElem.find('.label_fn').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_datetrustbalanceout');
        newElem.find('.input_fn').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_datetrustbalanceout').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_datetrustbalanceout').val('');

        // Last name - text
        newElem.find('.label_ln').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_datebankbalanceout');
        newElem.find('.input_ln').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_datebankbalanceout').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_datebankbalanceout').val('');


        // Insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
        $('#entry' + num).after(newElem);
        $('#ID' + newNum + '_title').focus();

        // Enable the "remove" button. This only shows once you have a duplicated section.
        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);

        // Right now you can only add 4 sections, for a total of 5. Change '5' below to the max number of sections you want to allow.
        if (newNum == 5) $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "limit"); // value here updates the text in the 'add' button when the limit is reached 
    });

    $('#btnDel').click(function () {
        // Confirmation dialog box. Works on all desktop browsers and iPhone.
        if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to remove this section? This cannot be undone.")) {
            var num = $('.clonedInput').length;
            // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
            $('#entry' + num).slideUp('slow', function () {
                $(this).remove();
                // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
                if (num - 1 === 1) $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
                // enable the "add" button
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);
            });
        }
        return false; // Removes the last section you added
    });
    // Enable the "add" button
    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);
    // Disable the "remove" button
    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Still haven't got anywhere with this, any further help?  [jsfiddle.net/vyvj3k53](http://%20jsfiddle.net/vyvj3k53)

Comment: Kindly provide fiddle for this

Comment: Sure thing, http://jsfiddle.net/vyvj3k53/. Thanks

Comment: Sorry to chase, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

> .unbind( eventType [, handler ] )
>
> Description: Remove a previously-attached event handler from the elements.

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

If i understand correctly, what you wanna do is clone the element with the data in it, but without the event handlers, right?
After having used .clone(true) on the element you want to clone, you can use .unbind() to remove previously-attached event handlers from the element.

Comment: actually what the OP requires is new Event handler for every cloned element, as he doesnt want to use the same event handler  for all the selects(original + cloned).

Comment: That is the outcome I'd like dreamweiver. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: what exactly are you doing in the event handler of the select irrespective of original or cloned select tags ?

Comment: Just trying to hide or show ID's based on selection within the select

Comment: See this fiddle jsfiddle.net/vyvj3k53.. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to chase, any ideas? I am at a loss